# rspec LoadError (Ruby on Rails, Michael Hartl's tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have searched for my problem and could not find it on stackoverflow. Found similar problems but none exactly like mine.
I am following Hartl's ruby on rails tutorial, however when i try to use rspec like he does i encounter this problem :

```
harrisspec $ rspec spec/
/home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/harris/rails_projects/myapp/spec/spec (LoadError)
    from /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Tried running it in the root of the application folder as well (another thread said this would work) but no dice :

```
harris~ $ rspec spec/
/home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/harris/spec (LoadError)
    from /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /home/harris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.14.6/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

How do I solve this ? I don't feel comfortable continuing with the tutorial without this as I am not sure how important this is for the development of an application.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception thrown from your second attempt suggests you ran it from your home directory, not the root application directory. Since (presumably) no rspec directory exists there, the `LoadError` makes sense. Going by the error in your first attempt, the correct directory would be `/home/harris/rails_projects/myapp`.

```
cd /home/harris/rails_projects/myapp
rspec spec/
```

Try that.

Comment: wow, how dumb of me. Can't believe I wasn't actually in the root application dir. Worked! Sorry for wasting time, thanks!

Comment: No worries. We've all wasted plenty of time on problems much dumber than that.